# Wiring diagram of this blue 12V switch?

Tags: piece-information, trains

I'm looking for a wiring diagram or some information about the internal connections of this [switch](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=1244) from the blue train era.

[image: LEGO 12V switch]

It is used for controlling the [automatic points](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=754-1), and is visible on the original box:

[image: LEGO automatic points]

The points connect to the back of the switch using a 3-pole connector:

[image: LEGO 3-pole connector]

I want to use a microcontroller to operate the points without manually pushing buttons. Since I don't have any of these, I cannot measure the connections (using a multimeter).

Does anyone own this switch, and cares to share some information?

---

This is how I think the switch works. I have tried wiring it this way and it works, however the points barely move. Perhaps the problem lies with the solenoids inside the points?

[image: LEGO switch schematic]

Answer (score 2):

In electrical engineering one might call it:
DPDT (Double Pole Double Throw) Momentary (On)-Off-(On) Reversing Polarity Toggle Switch.

[image: dpdt]

Momentary in this configuration means that it's spring loaded towards its centre position.

Edit: I'm not sure though, see the comment below. I have the remotely controlled switch points from the gray era and they work like above.

Comment: Are you sure it is a momentary switch? The 2-pole power supply connects to the side of the switch, and a 3-pole connector connects to the back leading to the points. From what I can see in the pictures it looks like the switch is a normal toggle switch with only two positions. Though I can't be sure. The points itself have a built-in switch which is toggled once the points are in position, unpowering the solenoids.

Comment: You might be right.

Comment: Yes, it looks like there is a difference between grey/blue era. The blue ones use two solenoids (one for each direction), so I guess the grey ones use one solenoid only (reversing the polarity to change the direction).

Comment: I've updated my question. Could you take a look?

Comment: I might ask TLG for this. There are several possibilties. I didn't know the switch has a 3-pole output. If it moves barely the two solenoids might be in series, but then, mentioning the interlocked end switch might obstruct power flow to switch back again. I don't like re invent the wheel. Neither do I own the switch nor the railswitch so I can't find out. What we need is a datasheet. TLG can clear this up for us.

Comment: Hey Niels, thanks again for your response. Actually the clue lies in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLzUG.jpg
I was using a 12V DC adapter, assuming the voltage for the points had to be the same as the train itself. Since all three connectors on the transformer are identical, a child could easily plug in the wrong connectors, so I assumed both would have to be the same voltage. It turns out the points actually use 16V AC. I will answer my own question once I have verified this, since I have no 16V adapter yet.

Comment: Ah. Nice find Midas. The transformer from the grey era has a blindplated 13VAC output which might work fine. The plate can easily be removed. https://questforbricks.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/the_transformer_3.jpg